# how do i cache specific files html / css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, gwt

how do i cache specific files in html ?
i have tried

```
meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="private" max-age="604800"
```

but when i click "audit" using google chrome inspect element
its giving me

```
Leverage browser caching (4)
The following resources are missing a cache expiration. Resources that do not specify an expiration may not be cached by browsers:
some.css
some.js
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:
some.html
some-hosted.html
```

how do i cache em ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=604800;private" />
```

Mind you this won't work for CSS/JS or anything else that isn't a HTML file. In those cases you need to set real HTTP headers server-side (which is usually done using webserver settings or via dynamic server-side languages like PHP, .Net, Coldfusion, etc...).

Comment: Why did you set it to private?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is to server your files through some kind of server side mechanism that attaches the right cache control headers to the http response.